# How to modify the value of text input with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I would like to dynamically modify the values of certain form elements, more specifically certain input text fields. So far, whenever I load my html page, I am just getting the blank input field, but I am expecting it to contain the value of `1`. Here is an example of how I am trying to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var myForm = $(this).getElementById('form1');
            myForm.elements['Q01'].value = '1';
         });
      </script>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <form id="form1">
         <input type="text" name="Q01" maxlength="1" />
      </form>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The reason this needs to be done dynamically is because the value of form could be different every time. Am I even approaching this correctly? Suggestions on how I can achieve my intended functionality?

-- EDIT --

None of the solutions seem to be doing the trick. Here is an update of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
                //$("#Q01").val("1");
                $("#form1 input[name='Q01']").val("1");
                //$("input[name='Q01']").val('1');
         });
      </script>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <form id="form1">
         <input type="text" id="Q01" name="Q01" maxlength="1" />
      </form>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am expecting when I load the page, that the input text will have `1` in it. But the input text keeps showing up empty. Any ideas?

-- EDIT --

Here is a solution derived from the answers from below that I like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
       <HEAD>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#Q01").val("1");
             });
          </script>
       </HEAD>
       <BODY>
          <form id="form1">
             <input type="text" id="Q01" name="Q01" maxlength="1" />
          </form>
       </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error which is why they aren't working in the ready handler. Your `)` should come after your `}`.

Comment: Good catch, that was why my first edit wasn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you could just change the `id` attribute to `name` in the input elements and then do something like this:

`$('#Q01').val('1')`

The val method sets the value sou can find more here: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Or $('input[name=q01]').val('1')

Comment: @Robert That would actually work better. I am a bit rusty on my jQuery

Comment: It's better to directly reference the ID instead of searching through all of the inputs for one with the name of "q01".

Answer (score 3):

You've got your ready handler correct. One of the great things about jQuery is its selector engine. I recommend taking a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to help familiarize yourself with it.

To do what you want, I'd recommend something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1 input[name='Q01']").val("1");
});
```

The `#form1` is the same as `document.getElementById("form1")`. The `input[name='Q01']` grabs all `input` elements that have a `name` attribute equal to `Q01`. The [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method sets the selected elements value to the string `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form input[name='Q01']).val('1');         
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $("input[name='Q01']").val('1');
```

But why not to set id's to your inputs?

Hope it works

Comment: good point, I should probably use ids. I can probably just get rid of name and just have id. Would there ever be any reason for the input to have a name if you can just reference it with id instead?

Comment: Well, yo shouldn't get rid of the name, if the value of the input will go to the server side.

Comment: are you saying that if I am going to do some php database interaction, then I should keep the name?

Comment: If you are going to catch up the input's value in the server side, the input must have a name (if I am wrong, please fix my edit). The inputs name is what is going on the request to the server side